# Converting a delimited string (or column) to rows in Oracle using a pre-defined system function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A few years ago in Oracle 10 or 9 I used a function which was something like "DBMS_COL_2_VAL" (This is definitely not the right function).

The purpose of this built in function is to convert the provided string to rows based on a specified delimiter.  I know that there are multiple ways of converting a delimited string to rows, but what I looking for is this specific function.

If you can help that would be great.

Please do not provide any solutions with CONNECT, CASE, or REGEX.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question.  In Sybase there was a great aggregate function LIST(<string>) which sort of did the opposite of what you are asking.  It would take a column and aggregate the rows into a comma-delimted list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function I was trying to find was `SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL`.

Technically speaking it does not convert a delimited string to column, but it converts a list of comma separated values to rows.  I realized that after I found an old [post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1422078&#1422078).

Sample code and results:

```
with test as  (
    select column_value AS c1  
      from table( SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL( 'a','b','c' ) )  
   )  
 select * from test;
```

Result:

```
c1   
__  
a    
b    
c
```

Comment: sys.odcivarchar2list seems to do something similar but is a bit more documented, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe thinking of this?

```
DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE ( 
   list   IN  VARCHAR2,
   tablen OUT BINARY_INTEGER,
   tab    OUT uncl_array); 

DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE ( 
   list   IN  VARCHAR2,
   tablen OUT BINARY_INTEGER,
   tab    OUT lname_array);
```