# How to check if all values of a column are part of the set?

Tags: plsql, set

Suppose I have a column with distinct values `(a,b,c,d,e,f) as values`.
In PL/SQL, how can I compare this column with a set, say, `(a,b,d,f)` and output an indicator?

My approach was:

```
select case 
when values in (a,b,d,f) then 'yes'
else 'no'
end
```

However this approach takes one value at a time and check if it is in `(a,b,d,f)`.

Comment: What data type is `values`, and how is `(a,b,c,d,e,f)` actually represented in that column?

Comment: Does the datatype really matter? Suppose they are varchar.

Comment: Yes, because I couldn't tell if you were talking about a delimited string, or an object type with multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare all values at once you can use the oracle's minus statement :

> select values
>   from your_table  minus 
>   (
>
> ```
>  select 'a' from dual union all
>  select 'b' from dual union all
>  select 'd' from dual union all
>  select 'f' from dual
> ```
>
> )

this will retrieve all of the values from your_table that are not in (a,b,d,f).

you can also use the SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL function to transfer a comma seperated list of values into a table (instead of using the

> select ... from dual union all ...

)

you can read more about teh SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825356/converting-a-delimited-string-or-column-to-rows-in-oracle-using-a-pre-defined).

Comment: But I want those that are in (a,b,d,f).

Answer (score -1):

You could try to select from your set of values, see [Oracle Documentation: Object Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjint.htm#i458240), and use a join-command.